# Script Database Execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Currently I'm building a SQL Server (T-SQL) script to create a full structure of a database and, after that, insert basic information. 
My system has 2 databases, one for transactional data and the other one is a DataWarehouse. Certain data inserted in the OLTP is replicated to the DW by triggers. 
I'm having the following problem.
Table A and B don't have relations in OLTP but B depends of A in DW. 
If I run inserts for A and B separately, everything runs perfect (insert and trigger replication), but, when I run the entire script, replication doesn't works because the insertion on B table doesn't finds the A data.

The script is build to run in SQLCMD mode.

thanks for help.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten actually ask a question. At this point all you have done is vaguely describe your system.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange, if your question the best practice to replicate your data, a start point is Replication (OLTP)---a Technical Reference Guide for Designing Mission-Critical OLTP Solutions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151784.aspx)

Comment: As far as I undertand the "question" : why don't you reorder your "big script" to put A concerned command before B concerned command? So that A data will be there when needed by B...

Comment: hehe, right @SeanLange, maybe I wasn't clear enought. 

Happens that when I run my script, the insertions on A table should be replicated to the DW database by the triggers, but when the insert in B table takes place and it is replicated to DW, it can´t find the needed data from DW.A for data integrity.
Is it there something that I have to do with the triggers to effectively save data on the table? 

hope to be clear.

Comment: I would urge you to read what you have posted and ask yourself if you think you could possibly answer this question based on what you have posted. At this point it isn't even clear what you are asking, let alone any details needed to have a chance at providing any insight. We can't see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: Thank your for your time. I have finally solved my problem.